# How to use d3d11 video processor rendering efficiently

Tags: c++, rendering, video-processing, directx-11

I am wrting a media player on Windows with **C++** and **D3D11 APIs**. I have decoded video frames by GPU. And I convert the NV12 frames to RGB for swap chain presenting by using `VideoProcessorBlt`. The images are displayed on a window successfully.

- But when I open the Windows Task Manager, it seems that the 3D, Video Decode, Video Processing modules of the GPU all are used. The utilization rate of the three modules keeps at about 7%.
- Contrast with Chrome or Edge browser, the browsers can play an MP4 file just using Video Decode module and Video Processing module. The utilization rate of the 3D module is 0%.

How do they implement this? I am wondering **how to render a frame efficiently**. Thanks.